# Regex for restoring broken JSON

Tags: json, regex

I am sending JSON-Data via POST to a PHP-Backend (I don't have any further access to it).

When I do a data export, the json is missing all quotes so it looks like this:

```
[
  { key: any text with spaces, emptykey: ,  foo: 0},
  {...}
]
```

I think this can easily be fixed - since none of my strings contains commas.

So I would assume one can split the whole JSON-Array into:
(1) Objects by `{..}`
(2) in key / value pairs by commas `,`

How would i do this with a simple RegEx-Replacement?

Comment: Check this: https://regex101.com/r/jqK12N/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really a *simple* regex-replacement, because it needs nested cascading regexes.

This will work *(but see also the @Mohammad Yusuf Ghazi's solution below)*:

```js
var src = '[{ key: any text with spaces, emptykey: ,  foo: 0}, { key2: other text with spaces, emptykey2: ,  foo2: 2},]';

var lookforObj = /\{([^}]*)\}/g;
function objRepl(match, obj) {
  return '{' + obj.replace(lookforPair, pairReplace) + '}';
}
var lookforPair = /\s*([^,]+)\s*(,?)\s*/g;
function pairReplace(match, pair, comma) {
  return pair.replace(lookforKey, keyReplace) + (comma ? ', ' : '');
}

var lookforKey = /\s*([^:]+):\s*(.*)/;
function keyReplace(match, key, value) {
  return '"' + key + '": "' + value + '"';
}

console.log(src.replace(lookforObj, objRepl));
```

EDIT: @Mohammad Yusuf Ghazi's solution is much more simpler and works well.
Its only disadvantage is that it doesn't take care of "normalizing" spaces and commas with respect of the JSON format rules.

Here is it:

```js
var src = '[{ key: any text with spaces, emptykey: ,  foo: 0}, { key2: other text with spaces, emptykey2: ,  foo2: 2},]';

console.log(src.replace(/(\w+):(\s*)(.*?)(,|})/g, '"$1":$2"$3"$4'));
```

Comment: Check this: https://regex101.com/r/jqK12N/3. You may use this regex and modify your answer.

Comment: cfeed this is neat: thanks! @Mohammad Yusuf Ghazi your regex did not work for me

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi Oh yes: this is pretty elegant. More simple than my own answer, so I don't want to "stole" it! Instead, _you_ should write your own answer with this.

Comment: @ManuKaracho Thanks for accepting my answer. But I'm surprised that the MohammadYusufGhazi's one doesn't work for you. As I just commented, it seems better.

Comment: @cFreed No issues, you take it and add 2nd method also if you will.

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi Like you, I actually discovered what was the issue, so I edited my answer as you proposed. And I just see you did it too :)

Comment: @cFreed :D I didn't see your update. Removed my answer when I scrolled back up :)

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi it was my fault, i implemented it the wrong way. Sorry! Definitely a perfect solution - thanks!